# How could I pass data to child method's interceptor from parent method in Unity

Tags: unity-container

Let's say I have two methods as below - Parent and Child. When logging Child method, I want to know which parentId is now being processed. That mean in the LogHandler of Child method, I could get the parentId. Is doing so possible in Unity?

```
    [LogHandler] //Unity call handler
    public virtual void Parent(int parentId)
    {
        //do something
        Child();
    }
    [LogHandler]
    public virtual void Child()
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for how to get the parent of an object, just use transform.parent.GetInstanceID() (or transform.root.GetInstanceID() if you want the top-most parent).